# Magento block loading order

Tags: php, magento

I'm a relative initiate to the Dark Arts (1.9) and I have a  question regarding the order in which modules load blocks.

I have a block that *should* be loaded by my other blocks (they extend it):

Block/Javascript.php:

```
class MyNamespace_MyModule_Block_Javascript extends MyNamespace_MyModule_Block_MyModule
```

Block/Mymodule.php:

```
class MyNamespace_MyModule_Block_MyModule extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
```

All working great on my dev stack, so I rsync the code up (carefully excluding files like app/etc/local.xml)

However, when I rsync my module up to the test server, Block/Javascript.php can't find the base block class (MyNamespace_MyModule_Block_MyModule) and returns an exception .. but it works just fine on my dev stack.

EDIT: Exception is

```
Fatal error: Class 'MyNamespace_MyModule_Block_MyModule' not found in 
/var/www/magento/app/code/community/MyNamespace/MyModule/Block/Javascript.php
on line 7
```

- All caching is turned off
- I even   rm -rf magento/var/cache/mage*
- Both servers (dev and test) are running the same version of Ubuntu

It's working fine on my local dev stack - models, blocks, helpers and resources are all set up properly in config.xml

I'm having to force loading of the base block to get it to work, which is not really the best way I think ..

Mymodule.php:

```
if (!class_exists('MyNamespace_MyModule_Block_MyModule'))
{
    class MyNamespace_MyModule_Block_MyModule extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
    {
    }
}
```

.. extended by Javascript.php:

```
if (!class_exists('MyNamespace_MyModule_Block_MyModule'))
    require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/Mymodule.php';

class MyNamespace_MyModule_Block_Javascript extends MyNamespace_MyModule_Block_MyModule
{
}
```

Also, any suggestions on the best way to quickly deploy from dev to test server would be appreciated (repo is git, with the .gitignore file ignoring everything it needs to)

EDIT:

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyNamespace_MyModule>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </MyNamespace_MyModule>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <mymodule>
                <class>MyNamespace_MyModule_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>mymodule_resource</resourceModel>
            </mymodule>
            <mymodule_mysql4>
                <class>MyNamespace_MyModule_Model_Resource_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <mymodule>
                        <table>mymodule</table>
                    </mymodule>
                </entities>
            </mymodule_mysql4>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <mymodule>
                <class>MyNamespace_MyModule_Block</class>
            </mymodule>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <mymodule>
                <class>MyNamespace_MyModule_Helper</class>
            </mymodule>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <mymodule_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>MyNamespace_MyModule</module>
                    <class>MyNamespace_MyModule_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </mymodule_setup>
            <mymodule_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </mymodule_write>
            <mymodule_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </mymodule_read>
        </resources>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mymodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MyNamespace_MyModule</module>
                    <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymodule>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodule>
                    <file>mymodule.xml</file>
                </mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <mymodule>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MyNamespace_MyModule</module>
                    <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymodule>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <default>
        <mymodule>
            <receipted>optional</receipted>
            <assurance>optional</assurance>
            <tailliftto>optional</tailliftto>
            <tailliftfrom>50></tailliftfrom>
            <handling_type>none></handling_type>
            <type>Carton</type>
            <handling_fee>0</handling_fee>
            <tailliftto>0</tailliftto>
            <tailliftfrom>0</tailliftfrom>
            <assurance>optional</assurance>
        </mymodule>
        <carriers>
            <mymodule>
                <active>0</active>
                <model>mymodule/shipping_carrier_mymodule</model>
                <title>Courier</title>
                <showmethod>1</showmethod>
                <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
                <specificcountry>AU</specificcountry>
                <specificerrmsg>Error when retrieving real-time shipping quotes</specificerrmsg>
            </mymodule>
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

.. and the layout/mymodule.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <block type="core/text"
                   name="google.cdn.jquery"> <!-- Ensure that jQuery is active with no-conflict set to $j -->
                <action method="setText">
                    <text><![CDATA[<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script><script>window.jQuery||document.write('<script src="/js/mymodule/jquery-ui/external/jquery/jquery.js">\x3c/script>');</script><script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict();</script>]]></text>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>

    <checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="content"><!-- Inserts a list of Australian towns for autcomplete -->
            <block type="mymodule/javascript" name="mymodule.javascript.towns"
                   template="mymodule/mymodule/jstowns.phtml">
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>mymodule/jquery-ui.min.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>mymodule/jquery-ui.theme.min.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>mymodule/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>mymodule/cart-complete.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>

    <checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="content"><!-- Inserts a list of Australian towns for autcomplete -->
            <block type="mymodule/javascript" name="mymodule.javascript.towns"
                   template="mymodule/mymodule/jstowns.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>mymodule/jquery-ui.min.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>mymodule/jquery-ui.theme.min.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>mymodule/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>mymodule/onepage-complete.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>

    <checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>
        <reference name="content">
            <block name="mymodule.shipping.options" type="mymodule/onepage_shipping_method_options"
                   template="mymodule/mymodule/Onepage/Shipping/Method/Options.phtml" output="toHtml"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>


</layout>
```

Cheers.

Comment: can you post the exception message

Comment: Edited. It's a 'class not found' error.

Comment: show your `layout` file and `config.xml` file

Comment: Done. But I'm pretty sure they're not the issue - those configs work fine on my dev stack (same version of Magento etc)

Comment: Cross-check your file names/paths and class names. there may be an issue due to server case sensitivity

Comment: Nope, both dev and test servers are running the same version of Ubuntu. Local dev machine is a VM via Vagrant. But thanks anyway.